# SMS permissions removed from androidmanifest.xml but still appear on manifest.class

Tags: javascript, android, permissions, manifest

sorry if the question is silly, but I'm new to this and still learning. I got this error on Google Play regarding the SMS and phone permissions, which were later on removed from androidmanifest.xml (the right one: src/main/androidmanifest.xml). When I tried to upload the updated apk, I still got that form for the permissions, which made no sense. It says I previously declared the SMS permissions, so I need to select the reason for it from a list. There's no way to skip this.

I looked a bit further on the code, and I saw all those SMS permissions still appear on manifest.class, which I cannot edit. I'm guessing the permissions are still on the apk therefore -despite not being in the androidmanifest.xml file? If so, how could I edit that to remove them for good?

If it's not that, then I'm guessing Google simply keeps on requesting that form and I would need to delete the app. But there's no option for that. And putting a completely new app would force me to change lots of things on the code (otherwise Google will flag it as repeated).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enrolled for beta testing. They might be reading SEND_SMS permission from your beta test application. Ask google to remove beta testing , that might solve your problem. thanx

Comment: The beta testing I have is from a few months ago. Would that still be the case? I'll ask them and will let you know if it works (although it takes them a while to reply)

Comment: yes that might problem, also 
1. Go to Release Management > Artifact Library
2. Expand Active APKs and Draft APKs
3. Expand Required Permissions for each APK

You may remove the unwanted APK's, and create a new release to see if they are still flagged incorrectly.